# Preg match won't match, can't figure out why

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using RegEx Helper website (http://regexpal.com/), and

```
ENTER.+Security
```

is matching the following:

> ENTER Open-Source Intelligence Team LSU Center for Animal Health, Food Safety, and Bio-Security

However, PHP will not `preg_match` it, and I cannot figure it out, I have been trying for a couple of hours now, and I feel really stupid that I can't get this little piece to match.

Is it apparent to anybody why? I have tried all kinds of combinations but, the most I can get it to match it ENTER. This is especially frustrating because this is my shortest and simplest RegEx by far, but it just will not match.

**Code**:

```
$title = '/(ENTER.+Security)/';


$file = shell_exec('pdf2txt.py docs/April.pdf');
preg_match_all($title, $file, $m);

print_r($m[0]);
```

When I remove the `preg_match` part, and I just print the $file, there are dozens of visual matches, but it just won't match it programatically.

All I see is this:

```
Array ( )
```

But the text it should be matching is here:

... 
/March/17031101.asp (accessed April 4, 2011). World Health Organization. State Food
 and Drug Administration Gets WHO Approval for Vaccine Regulatory System. March 1, 
2011. http://www.wpro.who.int/china/media_centre/press_releases/PR_20110301.htm 
(accessed April 4, 2011). ***ENTER Open-Source Intelligence Team LSU Center for Animal 
Health, Food Safety, and Bio-Security*** Special Interest Intelligence Report - Alert 
South Korea – Labeling Issues in Wheat Flour Mix Product...

Comment: Show your php code. How are you using preg_match?

Comment: Please post your preg_match line? I can't fault your regex in isolation. I suspect it's a problem with your PHP code, not the regex. The only alternative I can see is the string you're passing your regex isn't what you think it is.

Comment: It seems like the only problem it could be, based on the comments is in this python script... but it's weird, because it is working for all other matching

Comment: Might be a linebreak after the `ENTER` instead of just spaces. Try the regex `/s` flag.

Comment: Mario you are right. Fiddling with it now, thanks a ton!

Comment: Only I forgot that + is greedy, so it is matching everything in between the first ENTER and the last Security :) So it is matching at least :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accounting for multiple lines. There's a good chance when you are pasting it into that site that it's removing any line breaks.

```
preg_match('/ENTER.+Security/m',$str) //note the /m
```

The forward slash in the example is the delimeter. The following m tells it to match over multiple lines.

Comment: Ah... I think this is on the right track. Still not matching though.

Comment: `$title = '/ENTER.+Source/m';` gives me lots of matches for `ENTER Open-Source`, but I am trying to extend to `'/ENTER.+LSU/m';`, and it won't print any matches after that.

Comment: You are right, it is because of the lines that it isn't matching though. It is always matching up to the line, so when I am trying to match something on the next line, it won't match it.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as solved, because you got me to thinking about flags. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing code it's tough to know for sure what's going on, but my guess is that you're not delimiting your expression correctly. Try this:

```
preg_match('#ENTER.+Security#', $str);
```

Comment: Or the more conventional `/ENTER.+Security/`.